# Cannot access request body in a simple nextjs API call

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I am making this call from my nextjs frontend, running locally

```
const handleApiCall = async () => {

const requestOptions = {
  method: "POST",
  body: JSON.stringify({ hello: "world" }),
  headers: { "content-type": "application/json" },
};
try {
  await fetch("/api/generate", requestOptions)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => console.log(data))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));


} catch (error) {
  console.error("Error fetching data:", error);
}};
```

My api route is really simple:

```
export default async function POST(request) {
  const res = await request.json();
  console.log({ res });
 }
```

This throws an error -  ⨯ TypeError: request.json is not a function

If I try and log out request, it comes out as this:

```
{ params: {}, searchParams: {} }
```

Additional context:
I am using next 13.2

I am using Node 20

The call is coming from a client component.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had the wrong file name for the api.

It needs to be route.ts or route.js